# How to set volume on audio.play()

Tags: javascript, audio

Nothing fancy here, I just want the audio to play at a desired volume level.

```
var audio = new Audio('mysound.mp3');
audio.play();
```

I assume there are parameters I can pass into audio.play, but I've had a hard time finding a good reference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set volume like so

```
audio.volume = 0.75; // 75%
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you! All of the other references I had found were for specific use cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply just do this:

```
audio.sound = .5
```

Before you call `audio.play ()`